# Find difference between two data frames which has values in form of list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which has column values in the form of list.

I want to find the difference between two such dataframes.

I can do this is the values are single.

Using pd.concat()

```
difference_dbs2 = pd.concat([dic_asset2,dic_aut2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

But if values are in form of list i am getting error as:

```
>>> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Example dfs:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"A": ["S"], "B": [[1,2,3]]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"A": ["S"], "B": [[1,3,5]]})
```

The expected output should be

```
>>>   A  B    
    0 S [2]
```

That is values which are there in `df1` but not in `df2`

Real data is like :

```
HOSTNAME    DATABASE                                                     
EU2XXXXXXX  [ASSAS, ASAS, FSSD, DSD...]
```

Comment: Hi, can you reformat your question, including a code example?

Comment: Hi i have edited so thay df2 can look readable

Comment: Can you see now @DanielLima

Comment: It's still confuse... can you be more specific? Try add a dummy data here, so I would be able to replicate.

Comment: @DanielLima use the dummy data as specified, i have provided two data frames df1 and df2 and given an expected output

Comment: `drop_duplicates()` drops duplicate values in columns, so if you had two duplicate lists it might drop those. But it doesn't work because it's apparently using hash values to determine duplicates and lists aren't hashable (if it were a column of `tuple`s) it woild work. Albeit not as you want--`drop_duplicates()` has no concept of columns of lists or somehow performing set operations on them. That's just not what it does. Instead you might need to apply a custom function across the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:
Few assumptions:
(1) `A` represents partition i.e. we want to get diff of `B` per unique `A`

(2) You want to get diff as per sets theory i.e. `[1,2,3]-[1,3,5]=[2]`

```py
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({"A": ["S"], "B": [[1,2,3]]})

df2=pd.DataFrame({"A": ["S"], "B": [[1,3,5]]})

df1=df1.set_index("A")["B"].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()

df2=df2.set_index("A")["B"].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()

df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=list(df1.columns),how="outer",indicator=True)

df3=df3.loc[df3['_merge']=='left_only'].drop("_merge", axis=1).groupby("A", as_index=False).agg(list).rename(columns={0: "B"})
```

Output:

```py
   A    B
0  S  [2]
```